# Calculating Distribution percentage for multiple rows

Tags: excel, offset

3000 Rows of data and need a formula to be applied to calculate percentages in blocks of 4 rows.

I've tried dragging the formula down and playing around with Offeset function, but can't figure out a correct way for doing it.

THANKS EVERYONE FOR YOUR HELP, FOUND A SOLUTION! Looks like I should have mentioned that the counts were weighted so calculations were based off of the actual number not the rounded one displayed.

[image]

Comment: What formula would you manually put to get only the first 4? do not worry about the dragging, we need to know the base formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm assuming its 1/sum(1,0,5,1)... just the row as a percent of the block of 4 it's in.

Comment: =M11/SUM(M11:M14) is the base formula I'm using so far

Comment: Ok and the next down would be `=M12/SUM(M12:M14)`?

Comment: Or would it be `=M15/SUM(M15:M18)`?

Comment: That is correct @ScottCraner. So basically when I get to the next block of 4 I need it to jump down to SUM(M15:M18) and be able to carry that the entire way down.

Comment: But what would be divided `M15` or `M12`?  `M15` does not fit the expected output being shown for the third line. and `M12` you would run out of divisors before numerators.

Comment: @JvdV first block was `M11:M14`

Comment: @ScottCraner, I have mistaken your comment for ops

Comment: Something tells me you want to find the percentage of that value for B2 against all the other B2s

Comment: I think the following would come down to your base formula: `=INDEX(M:M,ROW()+(ROW(A1)-1)*3)/SUM(INDEX(M:M,ROW()+(ROW(A1)-1)*3):INDEX(M:M,ROW()+(ROW(A1)-1)*3+3))`, but it would not correspond with your first 11%

Comment: 1st Row:=M11/SUM($M$11:$M$14) Next Block of 4 would start =M15/SUM($M$15:$M$18) and then second row of that block would be =M16/SUM($M$15:$M$18). Hope this helps with the logic I'm trying to do

Comment: So the above worked for you? Either way, Scott got an answer up so if that worked you should accept it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=M11/SUM(INDEX(M:M,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*4+11):INDEX(M:M,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*4+14))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the only solution that seemed to work down the entire table.

Comment: No worries @Scott I spent hours trying to figure this out with my limited excel formula knowledge. Definitely going to spend a few more trying to understand it for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution not using `INDIRECT`:

```
=$M11/SUM(INDEX($M:$M,(ROUNDDOWN((ROW(1:1)-1)/4,0)*4)+11):INDEX($M:$M,(ROUNDDOWN((ROW(1:1)-1)/4,0)*4)+15))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the values in the far left column will always be the same.

```
=IF(A1="B2",C1/SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(A1)&":C"&ROW(A1)+3)),IF(A1="M3",C1/SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(A1)-1&":C"&ROW(A1)+2)),IF(A1="T2",C1/SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(A1)-2&":C"&ROW(A1)+1)),C1/SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(A1)-3&":C"&ROW(A1))))))
```

It's long but gives these results.

[image]